# Les « wapatos », « patates indiennes » etc. : sur quel nom s'arrêter ?

Tags: traduction, alimentation, régionalismes, emprunts, botanique

Je lis un [article](http://www.lapresse.ca/sciences/decouvertes/201612/27/01-5054894-un-potager-de-3800-ans-decouvert-en-colombie-britannique.php) dans lequel on [résume](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/12/ancient-underwater-garden-discovered-canada) une [étude](http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/12/e1601282.full) à l'effet que « les populations autochtones d'Amérique du Nord [Première Nation [Katzie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katzie_First_Nation) ([Halkomelem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halkomelem_language))] cultivaient déjà des potagers il y a près de [quatre millénaires](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holoc%C3%A8ne) » dans la région de la vallée du Fraser en Colombie-Britannique (Canada) ; ébranlant certainement l'image traditionnelle qu'on peut avoir du *chasseur-cueilleur* :

> Les fouilles ont mis au jour 3768 wapatos, également appelées «patates
>   indiennes». (*La Presse*)

Il s'agit du tubercule de la [*sagittaire latifoliée*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittaria_latifolia)/à larges feuilles ([USDA](https://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=SALA2)) qu'on appelle en [anglais](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=DUCK%20POTATO&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) *broadleaf arrowhead*, ou familièrement *wapato* ou *duck-potato* ([voir](https://youtu.be/cZj8z5U7eRE)). Il y a une particularité dans l'usage en français du Canada (entre [autres](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=wapato&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)) du terme [*indien*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1299270) (on a par exemple encore le fameux [*blé d'Inde*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2082788), pour le maïs) alors qu'ailleurs on comprendrait généralement *de l'Inde*. On n'a trouvé aucune référence à ces termes au *Grand Larousse gastronomique*, qui contient par ailleurs un entrée pour la [*patate douce*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2082785) (qu'il distingue de la *patate douce ross* et de la *violette* ; montre de plus l'igname, le manioc, le faro etc. ds. ses planches de légumes exotiques), qui n'est pas cultivée au nord...

---

Et donc si on n'est pas autrement déjà familier avec un terme que j'ignore, quel nom se propose-t-on d'utiliser pour nommer et décrire ce tubercule-là, par exemple dans une recette de [pâté chinois](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8873150) version Premières Nations, décoré avec des [têtes-de-violon](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870388) et servi avec un ketchup aux [atocas](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8873046) ?

- *Tubercule de...*, *wapato*, *patate* [+ adjectif, complément] etc. ; et surtout **pourquoi** (choisir la botanique, l'emprunt, la famille,
  le lieu etc.) ; et a-t-on des comparaisons avec des choix de noms en français pour d'autres noms d'aliments « exotiques » ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le nom wapatos, désignant le tubercule n'est pas utilisé en français. Cependant, comme tu l'as à juste titre mentionné, la plante de référence est la [Sagittaire à large feuilles](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittaria_latifolia).

J'ai fait des recherches sur cette plante, et je suis tombé sur [cet article](https://jardinage.ooreka.fr/plante/voir/467/sagittaire), mentionnant les noms suivants pour le tubercule :

- "*Pomme de terre des marais*"
- "*Pomme de terre des cygnes*"

> La sagittaire [...] porte un
>   autre nom – **pomme de terre des cygnes ou des marais** –, qui fait
>   allusion à un usage nutritif de cette plante originaire des diverses
>   zones tropicales et tempérées du globe, en Europe, Asie et Amérique.

Comment: Merci ! Le contraste entre la terre et le marais semble bien goûteux et on aime bien. On a aussi _flèche d'eau_ ds. votre article, évoquant la plante assurément. _Pomme de terre fléchée des marais_ me plairait... Vous _pommes de terre des marais_, vous la trouvez usuelle ou évocatrice ?

Comment: @red Ca reste subjectif, mais j'aurais tendance à préférer *pomme de terre des marais* à *pomme de terre fléchée des marais* (qui est un peu long/pompeux à mon goût). :)

Comment: Merci ! Je suis plutôt d'accord, et ce serait à dessein.